# Get file from shared OneDrive URL in PHP

Tags: php, url, download, onedrive

I'm writing something for a client that keeps their excel files in a onedrive account. Now my PHP script needs to read just that one file everyday. Is there any possibility to just make the user login once, or set the passwords in the script or set the shared url of the document, because I can't just have my client login everyday. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow apparently you can use the share url and then replace redir with download in the url.

Comment: Wouter, please make that an answer & mark it as then right one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use [authorization code flow](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm#code-flow) to get a refresh token that can be used to connect to OneDrive without requiring the user to login repeatedly.

You would need to build more of the auth flow into server-side code to use this flow, instead of using token flow and doing it all client side. However, it should be straight forward, and your app holds on to the refresh_token and uses it to get a new access_token each time you want to refresh data from OneDrive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have one question though: will I get a new refresh token everytime I request a new access token, or will it stay the same?

Comment: You will get a new refresh_token each time you redeem for an access_token. You should store the new refresh token value, since the newly minted refresh_token has a longer expiration time than the one you already have, although this isn't required (the original refresh_token isn't invalidated when used).

Comment: Okay ty, but I'll just use the other solution as that one is so much easier